# How to compute $\int^{\infty}_{0} t^{(\frac1n-1)}\cos t \,\mathrm{d}t$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function, closed-form

How to calculate the below integral?
$$
\int^{\infty}_{0} \frac{\cos t}{t^{1-\frac{1}{n}}} \textrm{d}t = \frac{\pi}{2\sin(\frac{\pi}{2n})\Gamma(1-\frac{1}{n})}
$$ 
where $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Just check the [Mellin transform](http://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMellin_transform&ei=1r0uULSpMOTYyAHqmYDADw&usg=AFQjCNFBJq9dQosoXIQCXXLJx_Iq09bv7g&sig2=t2SGfoQd-KAi-zySKu8X0A) of $\cos(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $t^{n^{-1}-1}\cos t$ as 
$$\frac12t^{n^{-1}-1}e^{it}+\frac12t^{n^{-1}-1}e^{-it}.$$

Consider the integral as complex contour integral and

- Turn the contour of integration for $\frac12t^{n^{-1}-1}e^{it}$ by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ counterclockwise (so that it becomes $t=is$, $s\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$), then
  $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac12t^{n^{-1}-1}e^{it}dt=\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}n^{-1}}}{2}\int_0^{\infty}s^{n^{-1}-1}e^{-s}ds=\frac{e^{\frac{i\pi}{2}n^{-1}}}{2}\Gamma(n^{-1}).$$
- Similarly, turn the contour of integration for $\frac12t^{n^{-1}-1}e^{it}$ by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ clockwise, then
  $$\int_0^{\infty}\frac12t^{n^{-1}-1}e^{-it}dt=\frac{e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}n^{-1}}}{2}\int_0^{\infty}s^{n^{-1}-1}e^{-s}ds=\frac{e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}n^{-1}}}{2}\Gamma(n^{-1}).$$

The sum of two integrals is equal to $\Gamma(n^{-1})\cos\frac{\pi}{2n}$ and it is an easy exercise (using Euler reflection formula $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi z}$) to show that this equals to the right side of your identity.

Answer (score 2):

It is well-known (and relatively easy to prove) that

> **Lemma.** If $f$ is improperly integrable on $(0, \infty)$, then $F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-sx} \, dx$ defines an analytic function for $\Re s > 0$ and
>   $$ \lim_{s\to0^{+}} \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-sx} \, dx = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx. $$

Then for $0 < \alpha < 1$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^{1-\alpha}} \, dx
&= \lim_{s\to0^{+}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^{1-\alpha}} e^{-sx} \, dx \\
&= \lim_{s\to0^{+}} \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(1-\alpha)}{x^{1-\alpha}} e^{-sx} \cos x \, dx \\
&= \lim_{s\to0^{+}} \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} u^{-\alpha} e^{-xu} \, du \right) e^{-sx} \cos x \, dx \\
&= \lim_{s\to0^{+}} \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(u+s)x} \cos x \, du \right) u^{-\alpha} \, du \\
&= \lim_{s\to0^{+}} \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(u+s) u^{-\alpha}}{(u+s)^{2} + 1} \, du \\
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^{1-\alpha}}{u^{2} + 1} \, du.
\end{align*}

Here, the interchange of two integrals is justified by the Fubini's theorem. Then by plugging $u = \tan \theta$, the beta function identity gives us

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^{1-\alpha}} \, dx
&= \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \tan^{1-\alpha}\theta \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{1}{2\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \beta\left( 1-\frac{\alpha}{2}, \frac{\alpha}{2} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \Gamma \left( 1-\frac{\alpha}{2} \right) \Gamma \left( \frac{\alpha}{2} \right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2\Gamma(1-\alpha)} \csc \left( \frac{\pi \alpha}{2} \right)
\end{align*}

as desired.

Answer (score 2):

A short cut is the Mellin transform technique (using the tables)

$$ F(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{s-1}f(x) dx .$$

Now, the [Mellin transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MellinTransform.html) of $\cos(t)$ is $$ \Gamma  \left( s \right) \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2} \,s \right) .$$

Then subs $s=\frac{1}{n}$, since $s-1=\frac{1}{n}-1$, gives

$$ I =  \Gamma  \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \cos \left( \frac{\pi}{2n}  \right) . $$

Answer (score 0):

This is just the definition of the [Incomplete gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function). The actual value can be found using the recurrence relation gotten by integration by parts as well as the definition of the Gamma function.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the incomplete Gamma function as both limits in the integral are zero and infinity...